# How do I make myself into someone who has strong emunah through tough times and become more religious ?

Tags: tefilla, faith-bitachon-emunah

I have been pretty religious my whole life but not 100%. I am 17 yr old boy and I go to shul on Shabbat for the last part of shacarit, the Torah reading and all of mussaf. My family is not very religious. We keep kosher but we aren't shomer shabbat. I went to yeshiva my whole life but left due to financial issues. I have been in public school for all of high school. I left yeshiva for high school and my brother left for public school since middle school. I overcame some rough times and I am happy that I am stronger Baruch Hashem but I am overcoming and having a hard time strengthening my emuna, so how do I?